# Import model from Blender to Unity with single texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender, uv-mapping

so I spend hours googling and "trial and error"ing, but I still could not figure this out.
I have (half) a chessboard modeled in Blender. I bake all my materials to a single png with UV mapping. It looks like this: [image: Blender Image]

I export the model as an .fbx and the baked texture as a .png. Both are imported to unity.
My goal is to have a **single** texture/material for the model.
The problem is, that unity still recognizes all squares etc. as separate objects with their own standard UV. When I map the combined texture to the model it is all messed up.
I can see why this happens, but not how to change the mapping so it picks out the right pixels of the texture. Is there something I can do to fix this?
Here is a picture of the model in unity.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to limit the export in Blender to only the object you want. You can do that in the export dialog for fbx on the right side. In your case, select "Limit to Selected Objects" while having only the chessboard selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I want to export the board and squares like I already did, which are multiple objects. I'm trying to figure out how to map those multiple objects to one single texture in Unity. At the moment Unity creates its own mapping and uses the entire texture for every object.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a work around which works perfect. You can merge objects in Blender. The steps I took:

- merge all squares and other objects into one. I used [this site](https://www.makeuseof.com/merge-objects-in-blender/) as a tutorial
- create a new uv map for this combined object
- bake the textures to the new uv map
- export model as .fbx
- export texture as .png
- import all to unity
- create material from texture
- apply material to model

Works perfectly fine for me :D